# How to check object equality using should.js with a property value as NaN

Tags: javascript, node.js, nan, should.js

I believe this is a bug in should.js due to a special value NaN as NaN is not equal to itself.

```
({
    a: 1,
    c: 3,
    b: 2,
    d: NaN
}).should.eql({
    a: 1,
    c: 3,
    b: 2,
    d: NaN
});
```

This test case fails while it seems pretty obivious that it should pass.

Any suggestions on how to go about on this test case?

Comment: This is a known bug in should.js: https://github.com/visionmedia/should.js/issues/38 (or maybe this is not quite the same case... hm.)

Answer (score 2):

`NaN` is special in that it is not equal to itself.

```
> NaN == NaN
false
```

This is not a bug. `NaN` is not equal to anything. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) for more info.

Comment: I said that in my question. I didn't ask why. I asked what to do with the bug.

Comment: @Juno It's not a bug.

Comment: should.js should be smart about it and check for NaN separately. This is a clearly a bug in should.js.

Comment: @Juno No, then by that logic this is a bug in JavaScript. `NaN !== NaN`.

Comment: so if this is not a bug, how will you ever check equality of an object with NaN value in should.js?

Comment: @Juno Where are you getting these NaN values in the first place?

Comment: I am adding them in my test cases

Comment: @Juno Why are you doing that? Don't.